# R - Concatenate two dataframes in Regards to Column #?

Tags: r

Given two dataframes a and b:

```
> a
X           a           b           c
1 -0.2246894 -1.48167912 -1.65099363
5  0.5559320 -0.87898575 -0.15634590
3  1.8469466 -0.01487524 -0.53098215
2 -0.6875051  0.23880967  0.01824621
11 -0.6735163  0.75485292  0.44154092


> b
X           a          c
6  0.4287284 -0.3295925
8  0.5201492  0.3341251
7 -2.6355570  1.7916780
9 -1.3645337  1.3642276
10 -0.4954542 -0.6660001
```

Is there a simple way to concatenate these so as to return a new data frame of the form below?

```
> new
X           a                   b           c
1 -0.2246894              -1.48167912       -1.65099363
2 -0.6875051               0.23880967        0.01824621
3 1.8469466               -0.01487524      -0.53098215
5  0.5559320               -0.87898575     -0.15634590
6  0.4287284                  NA            -0.32959248
7 -2.635557                    NA             1.7916780
8  0.5201492                   NA              0.3341251
9 -1.3645337                   NA              1.3642276
10 -0.4954542                  NA             -0.6660001
11 -0.6735163               0.75485292        0.44154092
```

I would like to cacatante the two data frames in regards to the order of X, I understand `rbind` does a similiar feature, but is there a way to keep the order in regards to X, even if some of the values are missing? For example, the new Frame has the order 1,2,3,5?

Comment: can you post `dput(a)` and `dput(b)` please?

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim I dont have this in R, it is just an example relating to a much larger data frame I am trying to work with.

Comment: Is there not a wait to rbind with regards to order for X?

Comment: you do it with `merge` in base R. or you use `dplyr` package `full_join()`.

Comment: Try the “bind_rows()” function from the dplyr package.

Comment: @Dave2e When I do that, they all aline in order except 2 or three of them, that go out of order

Answer (score 0):

```
new <- merge(a, b, all.x=TRUE, all.y=TRUE)
```

Or after

```
install.packages("dplyr")
require(dplyr)

new <- full_join(a, b)
```

Comment: That does merge the two together, but doesn't keep the order in regards to Column X? I would like Column X to go in order numerically, and display the data associated with it. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

The `bind_rows()` and `arrange()` functions in the dplyr package should do the trick.

```
a <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="X         a           b           c
1 -0.2246894 -1.48167912 -1.65099363
5  0.5559320 -0.87898575 -0.15634590
3  1.8469466 -0.01487524 -0.53098215
2 -0.6875051  0.23880967  0.01824621
11 -0.6735163  0.75485292  0.44154092")

b <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="X           a          c
6  0.4287284 -0.3295925
8  0.5201492  0.3341251
7 -2.6355570  1.7916780
9 -1.3645337  1.3642276
10 -0.4954542 -0.6660001")

library(dplyr)
bind_rows(a, b) %>% arrange(X)
```